# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

def regex(tex):
  text = re.compile('[А-ЯӨҮа-яөү0-9/s]')
  tex = text.sub("\n+", '\n', tex)
  tex = text.sub('\s+', ' ', tex) 
  tex = text.sub("\s+($)", '', tex)
  stopword = ['ч','л','аа', 'ээ', 'оо', 'өө', 'даа', 'дээ', 'дөө', 'доо']
  text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stopword])
  return text 

text = "Намайг Анужин \n\n\n гэдэг  дээ shushus " 
print(text)
print(regex(text))
```

[image]

Please tell me what the error is and how to fix it.

Comment: The arguments to `text.sub()` should be `replacement, string, count`. Why are you passing `tex` as the count? Shouldn't it be the string you want to do the replacing in?

Comment: You seem to be passing a regular expression to `text.sub()`. But `text` contains the compiled regular expression, you don't pass another regexp when you're substituting it.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: `А-Я` doesn't seem like a likely character range.

Comment: I think you want to use `re.sub()`, not `text.sub()`. It's not clear what the purpose of `text` is.

Comment: Can you post what you're expecting the `text` to be once it passes through the function `regex`?

Comment: My main question is what you're trying to do with this regexp: `'[А-ЯӨҮа-яөү0-9/s]'`

Comment: `А-ЯӨҮа-яөү0` will be (a variant of) the Cyrillic alphabet; that's fair enough

Comment: In particular, Mongolian Cyrillic alphabet

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the `text.sub("\n+", '\n', tex)` line where `text` is a *`Pattern`* and [*`Pattern.sub`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) singature is `Pattern.sub(repl, string, count=0)`. As you see, the `"\n+"` is a *`repl`*, `'\n'` is a *`string`* and `tex` is a *`count`* (an integer!).

Also, note that running `sub("\n+", '\n', tex)` before `sub('\s+', ' ', tex)` makes little sense since the `\s+` will match the `\n`s and will still replace them with a single space.

The `sub("\s+$", '', tex)` is also redundant since later, you split and re-join the string with whitespace, it will automatically strip whitespace on the left and right.

At some moment in the code later, you mixed `tex` and `text`, do not name separate variables almost identically, it is easy to mix them up.

You need to rearrange the code in the following way to clean the input string:

```py
import re

invalid_char_rx = re.compile('[^А-ЯӨҮа-яөү0-9\s]+')
stopword = ['ч','л','аа', 'ээ', 'оо', 'өө', 'даа', 'дээ', 'дөө', 'доо']

def regex(s):
  s = invalid_char_rx.sub(' ', s)
  s = ' '.join([word for word in s.split() if word not in stopword])
  return s

text = "Намайг Анужин \n\n\n гэдэг  дээ shushus " 
print(f"'{text}'")
print(f"'{regex(text)}'") # => 'Намайг Анужин гэдэг'
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Odz8Js).